# how to divide polygon into n equal area parts in python i need sub polygons coordinates

Tags: python, dictionary, gis

[image]

This is image which is draw outer polygon now I want to divide into multiple parts with equal area in python

please give suggestion and code sample

```
coordinate are = \[(17.436838, 78.466061), (17.433808, 78.488205), (17.415792, 78.486832), (17.412598, 78.464001)\]
```

I need sub polygon coordinates.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "please give suggestion and code sample" is not really how this community works: you need to explain to us what you have already tried to do and link some code if you want people here to help you. Please read How to Ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Not the right forum, but interesting question for me.
Idea: Look for the centroid. It's place marks, where to you can cut in any direction and both parts have equal area sizes.

There are 2 interesting options: you can split it in triangles between the vertexes end the centroid. The other idea is to split it horicontally or vertically depending on expansion.

The following code shows both ideas with an your data and another example- polygons.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

my_polygon = [(3,1),(9,1),(12,3),(14,5),(10,6),(5,7),(2,5),(0,2)]
your_polygon = [(17.436838, 78.466061), (17.433808, 78.488205), (17.415792, 78.486832), (17.412598, 78.464001)]
my_rect = [(0,0),(0,8),(2,8),(2,0)]
my_triangle = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)]
#my_polygon = [(x/15, y/10) for (x, y) in polygon]

(xm, ym, r, circle_points) = (6, 6, 5, 40)
my_circle = [(xm + math.sin(2*alpha*math.pi/circle_points)*r, ym + math.cos(2*alpha*math.pi/circle_points)*r) for alpha in range(circle_points)]

def calc_area(polygon):
    """
    calculates the area of a polygon

    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Simple_polygons

    parameters
        polygon - list of 2-dimensional points

    returns
        area
    """
    result = 0
    for i in range(len(polygon)):
        p0, p1 = polygon[i], polygon[(i+1) % len(polygon)]
        result += p0[0]*p1[1]-p1[0]*p0[1]
    return result / 2

def calc_centroid(polygon):
    """
    calculates the centroid of a polygon
    #https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_polygon

    parameters
        polygon - list of 2-dimensional points

    returns
        area

    """
    xs, ys, a = 0, 0, calc_area(polygon)
    for i in range(len(polygon)):
        p0, p1 = polygon[i], polygon[(i+1) % len(polygon)]
        xs += (p0[0]+p1[0])*(p0[0]*p1[1]-p1[0]*p0[1])
        ys += (p0[1]+p1[1])*(p0[0]*p1[1]-p1[0]*p0[1])
    return (xs/(6*a), ys/(6*a))

def split_triangles(polygon):
    """
    splits the polygon into triangles between centroid and and a vertex
    it only works for convex polygons

    parameters
        polygon - list of 2-dimensional points

    returns
        list of polygons (triangles)

    """
    result = []
    xs, ys = calc_centroid(polygon)
    for i in range(len(polygon)):
        p0, p1 = polygon[i], polygon[(i+1) % len(polygon)]
        result.append((p0, p1, (xs,ys)))
    return result

def split_ortho(polygon):
    """
    splits the polygon orthogonal concerning centroid into two parts
    if x- extension bigger than y- extension, then vertical split, otherwise horicontal

    it only works for convex polygons

    parameters
        polygon - list of 2-dimensional points

    returns
        list of polygons

    """
    ps = calc_centroid(polygon)
    x = [p[0] for p in polygon]
    y = [p[1] for p in polygon]
    parts = [[]]

    split_index = 0 if (max(x)-min(x)) > (max(y)-min(y)) else 1

    for i in range(len(polygon)):
        p0, p1 = polygon[i], polygon[(i+1) % len(polygon)]
        parts[len(parts)-1].append(p0)
        if (p0[split_index] < ps[split_index] and ps[split_index] < p1[split_index]) or\
            (p0[split_index] > ps[split_index] and ps[split_index] > p1[split_index]):
            #Nenner kann bei konkaven Polygonen nicht 0 werden, denn dann müsste diese Kante senkrecht zum Schwerpunkt verlaufen
            #if p0[split_index] < p1[split_index]:
            if True:
                BA, BX, BE = p0[split_index], ps[split_index], p1[split_index]
                HA, HE = p0[(split_index+1) % 2], p1[(split_index+1) % 2]
                HX = HA+(BX-BA)*(HE-HA)/(BE-BA)

            psplit = [0,0]
            psplit[split_index] = ps[split_index]
            psplit[(split_index + 1) % 2] = HX
            parts[len(parts)-1].append(tuple(psplit))
            parts.append([tuple(psplit)])
    return (parts[1], parts[2]+parts[0])

functions = {0:(split_triangles, 3), 1:(split_ortho, 5)}
areas = {0:my_polygon, 1:your_polygon, 2:my_circle, 3:my_triangle}
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 4, ncols = 4)

for key_area in areas:
    polygon = areas[key_area]

    for key_function in functions:
        func, stepcount = functions[key_function]

        parts = [polygon]
        for i in range(stepcount):
            new_parts = []
            for j, p in enumerate(parts):
                new_parts.extend(func(p))
            parts = new_parts

            if i==0:
                for p in parts:
                    ax[key_function*2][key_area].add_patch(plt.Polygon(p, ec = "k"))
                    ax[key_function*2][key_area].autoscale()

        for p in parts:
            ax[key_function*2+1][key_area].add_patch(plt.Polygon(p, ec = "k"))
            ax[key_function*2+1][key_area].autoscale()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

To answer your last question: Of course you can easy adapt this code for a given number of "n". A simple way - so simple, that I don't like to do it - is to split the polygon (should be convex) beginning from one edge into polygons / triangles of the given size. The way: You calculate the area of the first three points. If this is smaller than total area divided by "n", you calculate the next triangle, until the sum is greater or equal than your wish. If it is greater, you can easy devide the opposite side that way. The first part is the end of your last polygon, the other is the beginning of the new one.
But there are many variations of this, you could start in one edge or in the center, in any other given point inside your shape - as you like.

Comment: thanks this code work . but if  we want to divide polygon into specific parts it possible ?